# CollectionViewLayout Direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

After working with collection views for so long I feel ashamed to ask:

**Apart from subclassing the flow layout**, how do I get a collection view to render cells in the direction I want? It seems that when the 'scrollDirection' of the layout is Horizontal the cells are arranged vertically so that the second will be under the first while the whole collection view will scroll to the right (as expected). How do I get the same horizontal scrolling but with cells that render horizontally as well, with the second being to the right of the first?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind **without subclassing the flow layout** is to make the cell height equal to UICollectionView height. That way cells can't fit in a vertical order and will all be in a horizontal space.